# How to get the two highest values in a HashMap<String, Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I have a HashMap made of two types: `String` **as Keys**, which are Player names and `Integer` **as values**, which are scores.

I am creating a ranking system, and for that, I need to get the **two highest values from this HashMap**, so the top two players that were `put` into it.

---

For example:

If these were the values of my HashMap:

```
  Key         Value

String1         1
String2         2
String3         3
String4         4
String5         5
```

I would want a way to only return `String4` and `String5`.

I thought that getting the `entrySet` would be enough, but there's no `get` method in a Set, so I can't get value `0` (highest) and value `1` (second highest).

I also tried using

```
Collections.max(map);
```

And it wouldn't accept a HashMap as an argument

And

```
final String[] top = new String[1];
int topInt = 0;

map.forEach((s, i) -> {if (i > topInt) top[0] = s;});
```

But that didn't quite work either, it was way too slow for my performance.

**How do I obtain both highest values?**

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean a `Map<Integer, String>` or a `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: Have you tried writing any code at all e.g. iterating over the map?  Or better yet Collections.max() (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)), twice, a second time after your remove the maximum.

Comment: Also, what is the context of this application?  Is performance a concern?  If so, iterating through the hashmap every time a value changes might not be the best solution.

Comment: Are you assuming your Value is unique?  What if three Strings have the highest value?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried to be more specific, can you verify if that solves the issue?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I tried to add what I tried to do. Could you verify if my question was improved by that and meet your requirements?

Comment: @alexD I tried to clarify both your questions in my question, could you verify it and see if that's right?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this. I haven't tested it, let me know if I overlooked something.

```
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
String highestString = null;
int secondHighest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
String secondHighestString = null;
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : yourHashMap.entrySet())
{
    if(highest < pair.getValue())
    {
        secondHighest = highest;
        secondHighestString = highestString;
        highest = pair.getValue();
        highestString = pair.getKey();
    }
}
```

Also as others have stated in the comments; this is probably not the best approach, as you could have multiple values of the same value with different keys. If indexing is what you are after use an `array`, `ArrayList`, or something from the `java.util.Collections` class.

Comment: Plus 1, I would hope you haven't tested this as it doesn't compile but you have the right idea.

Comment: My in-memory JRE not too reliable either.  It was your `pair` declaration.

Comment: @MeetTitan
What if there were 5 values?

Comment: @Kerooker, the code works assuming you don't have duplicate values.

Comment: @MeetTitan
Hm..Then I don't know what to do haha

Comment: @Kerooker, Run the code, then `System.out.println(String.format("key: %s, val: %d", highestString, highest);`

Comment: @MeetTitan I have to put 5 values in order (like a ranking), assuming that there might be draws

Comment: @Kerooker, I'm unsure of what you're asking. The code I gave you accomplishes the goal you requested. If you feel I've helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. If you have another question consider posting another question. Maybe I'll see it. :-)